# Passport.js Google authentication returns blank error

Tags: angularjs, authentication, callback, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Trying to use passport.js in my Angular app to use google authentication.

The way I have my express endpoints set up is:

```
app.set('client-google-signin-path', '/google');

app.route('/auth/google')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
      var mobileApp = req.headers.origin;
      passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'], callbackURL: mobileApp + req.app.get('client-google-signin-path')})(req, res, next);
    });

app.route('/auth/google/callback')
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
      //NEVER MAKES IT HERE
      var mobileApp = req.headers.origin;
      passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile', 'email'], callbackURL: mobileApp + req.app.get('client-google-signin-path')},
        function(err, user, info) {
          var profile;
          if(err) return next(err);
          if(!info || !info.profile) return res.status(400).send("Profile not available.");

          // Grab the profile info returned from google.
          profile = info.profile._json;
          //model logic
          User.findOne({ 'email': profile.email }, function(err, user) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            if(!user) return res.status(400).send("There does not appear to be an account that matches, you may need to create an account and try again.");

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
              if(err) return next(err);
              return res.status(200).send(user);
            });
          });
          res.status(200);
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

My controller looks like:

```
  $scope.signInGoogle = function() {
    return $http.get(backendConst.location + 'auth/google')
      .success(function(url) {
        // Redirect to google.
        $window.location.href = url;
      });
  };

  $scope.signInGoogleCallback = function() {
    return $http.get(backendConst.location + 'auth/google/callback', {
      params: $location.search()
    })
    .success(function(user) {
      $scope.gRes = 'Success!';
      $location.search('code', null);
      $location.hash(null);
      AuthModel.setUser(user);
      $location.path('/');
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      $scope.gRes = 'Authentication failed, redirecting.';
      $location.path('/authenticate');

    });
```

And for good measure, my dinky little /google redirect page is:

```
<div class="container clearfix" ng-init="signInGoogleCallback()">
  <h1>Google YO!</h1>
  <h4>{{gRes}}</h4>
</div>
```

So what's happening is that it brings in the "log in with google" page, lets me select my account, then when it calls the callback it quickly flashes the /google view but then kicks me back out into /authenticate, the view I started in.  Doing some debugging shows that

```
return $http.get(backendConst.location + 'auth/google/callback', {
      params: $location.search()
    })
```

is throwing a blank "err" even though in my endpoint logs it's saying that /auth/google/callback returned a 200.  I'm not sure what's happening.  I know this looks needlessly complicated but I do it this way with facebook and passport.js and everything works fine, except my endpoint logs are showing that with facebook the parameter "?code=" is being added to the /auth/facebook/callback url, like I'm trying to do with {params: $location.search()} in my google callback function in my controller.  Debugging into the endpoint shows that it never makes it to where I left the //NEVER MAKES IT HERE comment, but when removing the {params: $location.search()} option it makes it passport.authenticate but not beyond.  I'm completely stumped.  Again I should stress that I handle facebook authentication the exact same way and it works perfectly.